# Filestreaming to server

Tags: delphi, filestream

i'm trying to send an mp3 file over network to a server where it is played by a media player. the code i have so far works for strings but not for files. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

here is the sourcecode

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyStream : TFileStream;
  MP3 : TFileName;
  Len : Int64;
begin
  MP3 := GetCurrentDir + '\Clocks.mp3';
  MyStream := TFilestream.Create(MP3, fmOpenRead);
  try
    Len := Length(MP3);
    MyStream.WriteBuffer(Len, SizeOf(Len));
    MyStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(MP3)^, Len * SizeOf(MP3));

    MyStream.Position := 0;

    TcpClient1.Active := True;
    TcpClient1.SendStream(MyStream);
    TcpClient1.Active := False;
  finally
    MyStream.Free
  end;
end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TForm1.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
var
  MP3 : TFileName;
  Len: Int64;
begin
  //Receives the message from the client
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Len, SizeOf(Len),0);
  SetLength(MP3, Len);
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(MP3)^,Len * SizeOf(MP3), 0);

  MediaPlayer1.FileName := MP3;
  MediaPLayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

The problem starts when the program try's to write the stream so Im not even sure the receiving end works

Ps. Im a beginning programmer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are sending widestrings, which means you have to use:

```
Len :=Length(mp3) * SizeOf(Char);
```

Secondly, you dont need the cast. This should do fine:

```
myStream.Write(mp3[1],Len);
```

Third, if tcpSocket is non-blocking, then you must not disable it directly after sending the stream, that will cut the connection before it even gets started. Use the events to know when the data is sent.

To avoid all this, use TReader and TWriter on your streams. That way you dont have to care about string datasize on both sides, just the stream size.

Tip: Always send a magic value (a constant value) first, that way you can check on the other side if it is a valid data-package.

Here is one way you could do it:

```
Procedure TForm1.WriteMP3File(aFilename:string);
var
  mData:  TMemoryStream;
  mFile:  TFilestream;
  mWriter:  TWriter;
Begin
  mData:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    mFile:=TFileStream.Create(aFilename,fmOpenRead);
    try
      mWriter:=TWriter.Create(mData);
      try
        // Write header code, any number will do
        mWriter.WriteInteger($BABE);

        // Write the filename
        mWriter.WriteString(ExtractFileName(aFilename));

        //Write size of MP3 file
        mWriter.WriteVariant(mFile.Size);

        //Push all data into the mData stream
        mWriter.FlushBuffer;

        //Append MP3 file
        mData.CopyFrom(mFile,mFile.Size);
      finally
        mWriter.Free;
      end;

      mData.Position:=0;
      socket.sendstream(mData);

    finally
      mFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    mData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And reading it is done in reverse on the server:

```
Procedure TForm1.ReadMP3File(aMp3PlayPath:String;aStream:TStream);
var
  mReader:  TReader;
  mFileData:  TFileStream;
  mName:    String;
  mSize:    Int64;
Begin
  try

    mReader:=TReader.Create(aStream);
    try
      if mReader.ReadInteger=$BABE then
      Begin
        mName:=mReader.ReadString;
        mSize:=mReader.ReadVariant;
      end else
      raise exception.Create('Invalid datapackage error');
    finally
      mReader.Free;
    end;

    if mSize>0 then
    Begin
      mFileData:=TFileStream.Create(aMp3PlayPath + mName,fmCreate);
      try
        mFiledata.CopyFrom(aStream,mSize);
      finally
        mFiledata.Free;
      end;
    end;

    //Now you can play the file


  finally
    //Release stream or do it elsewhere
    aStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: it was not my intend to just send the name of the file. how do declare that im working with a file not a filename or do i even need to declare like so

MyStream := TFilestream.Create(GetCurrentDir + '\Clocks.mp3', fmOpenRead);

if so how do i set the size of the buffer if i cant point to the filename variable.

Comment: Added an example to the answere :)

Comment: Add a like and up the value on the answer :)

Comment: i would if my rating was high enough m8, i did like it tho

Comment: when i start implementing you code i get a error message here:        mWriter := TWriter.Create(mData);   would this do?    mWriter := TWriter.Create(mData, 0);

Comment: Sorry, you need TWriter.Create(mData,1024); This is the size of the writers cache. When you type flushbuffer, this buffer is pushed to the target stream. It is automatically flushed if you write data beyond that size.

Comment: ah right, so this is the way we break up the data. Also you wrote socket.sendstream(mData); should i change that to TcpClient1.sendstream(mData);?

Comment: on the serverside. the aStream variable, would that be TcpServer1.ReceiveBuf? If so, what is the void type?

Comment: It is common to accept the answer if you actually find it useful. I spent 15 min. of my life to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

First this code:

```
MyStream.WriteBuffer(Len, SizeOf(Len));
MyStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(MP3)^, Len * SizeOf(MP3));
```

In this you are attempting to change the MP3 file content and it would corrupt your mp3 file. Fortunately you opened the file as `fmOpenRead` which is why `MyStream.WriteBuffer` fails.

If you want to send filename to the server you will have to send it separately (for example by using `TTcpClient.SendBuf`.

On the server side you are currently only reading file name and ignoring the file content itself.

```
ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Len, SizeOf(Len),0); // this reads length of the filename
SetLength(MP3, Len);
ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(MP3)^,Len * SizeOf(MP3), 0); // this reads filename itself
// Now you should receive file contents itself and store it on the server
```

After you have stored the file on the server you can play it using MediaPlayer1. If you don't store the file in the server you can only play the file if server and client are on the same machine (unless if media player works with url or network path as FileName).

Comment: ok so when i have stored the file in memory, i can start playing it and only when it is finished playing i free the stream. Am i right?

Comment: To play from memory you have to use directMedia which is more complex. Save the file to a filestream and then play the file.

Comment: is the mp3 format even compatible for mediaDirect or should i start looking into voip specific codecs for that one

Comment: Mp3 is supported by windows. If you want to play from memory google "delphi mp3 player" and you will probably find a lot. Plenty of delphi codec wrappers out there, but for simplicity i would stick to file based solutions.